# OpenSSL: accept TLS connection and then transfer to another process

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, openssl, posix

We have a (Linux) server running two processes, A and B. Currently, clients establish a connection to process A, which then passes the resulting socket's file descriptor to process B, allowing process B to use the existing fd/socket to communicate seamlessly with the client. The client and process B then perform a TLS handshake and continue talking on the resulting TLS connection.

(I'm leaving out a lot of details here, but yes, there *is* a good reasons for having process A act as an intermediary instead of just connecting to process B directly)

Now, because of *`<long complicated story involving new client applications and websockets>`* it looks like we may have to perform the TLS handshake in process A, and then transfer the established TLS connection to process B.

Is that possible? The underlying socket's file descriptor can be copied (we do that already), and at least in theory, the internal TLS state data could also be copied and used to reconstruct the TLS connection in process B, effectively taking over the connection.

But does OpenSSL expose any facility like that?
I found the function `d2i_SSL_SESSION` which seems to do something similar for an OpenSSL session object, but being quite new to OpenSSL, I'm not sure if that is sufficient. There are sessions, context, BIO's and a bunch of other complicated-sounding terms involved. How much would have to be serialized and transferred to process B for this to work? And how would it be done in practice?

The switchover is required to be 100% transparent to the client: it must simply perform an SSL handshake against a given IP/port, and then continue talking on the resulting socket, with no knowledge of the fact that one process accepts the connection and performs the TLS handshake, and another then handles all subsequent communication.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing SSL context across processes is indeed possible. However, then the SSL-session-context would need to reside in a shared memory location which is accessible to both the processes (since for specific reasons unknown) we want the actual handshake to be done in process A and do the data I/O in process B.

First step is to register the call-backs for
    SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb(ctx, shared_ctx_new_cb);
    SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb(ctx, shared_ctx_get_cb);
    SSL_CTX_sess_set_remove_cb(ctx, shared_ctx_remove_cb);

Ensure appropriate SSL-session-context always get created in shared memory (or atleast returns a serialized and ready to use addressable pointers to SSL_SESSION

To (de)serialize the SSL_SESSION 'C' struct use the available API  d2i_SSL_SESSION(...) and i2d_SSL_SESSION(...)

A working project using this approach an sample code at https://github.com/varnish/hitch/blob/master/src/shctx.c

Comment: It is a decent answer, but it is always better to add snippets of code directly into the answer.  It is hard to argue that gitub might go bankrupt and offline.  Yet, varnish may change its source structure and your link will become invalid.  There's no need to add hundreds of lines of code, just some 10-20 lines.  Also, it is wise to make a summary of the process model instead of pasting a link.  It will make a much better answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on practice, but as far as I remember after the connection is created on socket level it is initialized by openssl and then you read/write with SSL_read and SSL_write. They accept socket fd as parameter. The connection itself (from SSL side) is represented with SSL_CTX SSL structs.

So in theory that sounds possible, but as I said I have never tried it in the real world.

Comment: But that requires the `SSL_CTX` and `SSL` structs to be transferred to the other process, which is where it gets interesting...

Comment: True.. I assumed that the new process gets forked, but the case in question is different.

Comment: Yeah, that would have simplified the situation. Sadly, they're not forked (process B already exists prior to the client connecting)

Comment: It is not clear to me how this would be viable even if you were forking the new process.

Comment: After the fork, the new process is a 'copy' of the old one.

Answer (score 1):

A recent kernel patch may make it possible by giving a normal fd for a TLS connection. See the page "[TLS in the kernel By Jake Edge
December 2, 2015](https://lwn.net/Articles/666509/)". I also cross posted to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37900102/362754).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, since part of the initial handshake is key exchange, and the keys are required for the ongoing communication. Process B would need to know the key being used by the remote end and by process A.

Comment: All this is saved in the SSL context so in theory it may be transferred to the other process,

Comment: Yes, but does OpenSSL provide any way to serialize the SSL context? I don't think it does.

Comment: Given that the processes run on the same server, and both are trusted, there's no problem in letting them both access the key. I guess the real problem is in all the state *other* than the key.

Comment: There's no problem theoretical problem in letting them access the same keys; the problem is getting the keys - and the rest of the connection state - from one process to another. As I say, there's no way to serialize the context.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like way more trouble that it's worth... consider other designs, e.g. proxy the connection through A on behalf of B using the loopback interface for example.

Comment: At the moment we *are* considering other options as well as this one. But there are downsides to all the alternatives (including your suggestion of proxying). I left out a lot of details in my question which would explain why we would prefer this solution, but if it can't be done, or if it's too much trouble, we will find another solution