# How to accept SSL connection in one process and reuse the same SSL context in another process

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl, openssl

I have spent quite some time doing my research on how to tackle this problem but could not find a working solution yet.

**Problem:**
I am using OpenSSL library and linux.
I have a server process P1 accepting SSL connection from SSL client. P1 does tcp_accept() and then SSL_accept() and exchanges some protocol data with client with SSL_read/SSL_write(). Everything is fine till this point. Now by design P1 needs to fork a child process C1 to serve the client from this point onwards. C1 uses execve call to re-image itself and spawn a different binary. C1 still needs to talk to the SSL client over the same SSL connection that was used in P1. The problem is since C1 is a completely different process now how it can re-use the existing SSL connection for that client? I am able to pass the underlying TCP socket descriptor from P1 to C1 as it is maintained in kernel but I can not pass the SSL context since it's maintained in the Openssl Library.

I saw this tread on stackoverflow but unfortunately no solution is mentioned.
[OpenSSL: accept TLS connection and then transfer to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426246/openssl-accept-tls-connection-and-then-transfer-to-another-process?)

**Possible Solution:**
I am not sure if anybody has already solved this kind of problem but I tried following.

1. I thought I can just create a new SSL conctext and do SSL renegotiation in the new child process. So in C1 I created a new SSL context over the same underlying tcp socket fd and tried to do SSL renegotiation. Here is what I did (Omiting the SSL_ctx initialization part)

   ssl = SSL_new(ctx) // ctx is initialized the same as it was done in P1 server
   SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd); // fd is the underlying tcp socket fd passed from P1 to C1
   SSL_set_accept_state(ssl);
   SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, 0);
   SSL_renegotiate(ssl);
   SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
   ssl->state=SSL_ST_ACCEPT;
   SSL_do_handshake(ssl);

But the renegotiation does not succeed and returns me an Openssl Internal error from first SSL_do_handshake() call. I am not even sure if this can really be done. The other solution that I can think of is following.

2. Somehow transfer the whole SSL context for that client from P1 to C1. How efficiently this can be done? I can think of shared memory for this but not really sure about what all internal state OpenSSL maintains that needs to copied into the shared memory. 
   This seems to be the most logical solution but I don't have much insight into OpenSSL code to do this.

Has anybody faced similar problem and solved it?
I will really appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you got any solution of this problem?,if yes then please tell me solution of it

Answer (score 3):

A search online finds this discussion:

[Passing TLS sessions between programs](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Passing-TLS-sessions-between-programs-td10087.html)

> Once you have the SSL_SESSION, convert it to ASN1 (via i2d_SSL_SESSION) and dump it to a file. Read that file in with your second program and convert it back from ASN1 to SSL_SESSION(via d2i_SSL_SESSION) and add it to the SSL_SESSION cache of the SSL_CTX (via SSL_CTX_add_session).

> I found in doc/ssleay.txt :
>  
>   [...] 
>   The PEM_write_SSL_SESSION(fp,x) and PEM_read_SSL_SESSION(fp,x,cb) will 
>   write to a file pointer in base64 encoding. 
>   What you can do with this, is pass session information between separate 
>   processes. 
>   [...]

So you need to serialize the SSL session data from P1 and pass it to C1 to deserialize, along with the socket descriptor.  You can then create new `SSL` and `SSL_CTX` objects in C1 and associate them with the socket and deserialized session data so C1 can take over the conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I did this but C1 is not able to send the data out with the resumed session. P1 does SSL_accept(), SSL_get_session(), i2d_SSL_SESSION() and then fork C1. C1 does SSL_new(), SSL_set_fd(), d2i_SSL_SESSION(), SSL_CTX_add_session(), SSL_set_session(), SSL_set_accept_state(), SSL_write() in order. But the data is not going out of the system. Am I missing something more?

Comment: Are any errors being reported by OpenSSL, especially on the `SSL_write()` in particular?

Comment: SSL_write() does not report any errors. What could be other possibilities?

Comment: Are you sure the underlying socket simply isn't buffering outgoing data? What kind of data are you actually sending? How are you monitoring that data is not leaving the system?

Comment: I send some protocol data about 12 bytes in length. There is no buffering at underlying sockets(disabled naggle's algorithm). I used tcpdump to capture packets on the system where I see all packets exchanges going fine as long it's happening in the context of P1, but nothing in C1. I have waited long enough to verify that. I also read in the openssl man page that SSL_set_session is only useful for SSL client. If thats the case then how do SSL server re-use session from session cache? I am not really sure if my API calls are right.

Comment: Just followed the steps above, but then I realized this won't work. Since you can only use SSL_set_session() in the a client context(connect_state), not in the server context(accept_state).

Comment: As far as I can see, a SSL_SESSION is just some kind of handshake speedup cache. The actual connection is the SSL object, which [isn't movable](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Passing-TLS-sessions-between-programs-tp10087p42191.html). This answer doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for "tls kernel mode" and found a kernel patch to give a normal fd for a TLS connection. Thus the fd can be passed to other processes as a normal socket.

The page is titled "[TLS in the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/666509/)" on lwn.net. Towards the bottom there are interesting discussions about it. Hope it may get its way into the kernel mainline. Or else wish someone may come up with a production quality patch set so people can make real use of it.

If you know some real products are using it, probably it's a good idea to share it here.

Update: [This open source project "TLSe" as a replacement to openssh](https://github.com/eduardsui/tlse) is specially designed for exporting context to another process.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff a security engineer has nightmares about. Reminds me a bit of rendering fonts in the Windows kernel

Comment: Wonder if other ways of passing a TLS connection among processes exist. Maybe something like an active fd with which the process can be a stage in a pipeline?

Comment: Shared memory seems like the obvious choice

Comment: Shared memory can be the data part. How about the trigger from one process to the other? What would be least cost and fastest?

Comment: Message paasing? Don't know exactly, but linux really has plenty of options for IPC. You can even send a file descriptor over a unix socket