# MITM proxy supporting TLS renegotiation

Tags: ssl, proxy, mitmproxy

I have specific scenario

[OpenSSL: accept TLS connection and then transfer to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767529/openssl-how-to-accept-ssl-connection-in-one-process-and-reuse-the-same-ssl-cont)
and [OpenSSL secure renegotiation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47811/openssl-secure-renegotiation)

[image: 2]

Here, P1 process forks a child process C1.
This scenario works fine. No issues with this.

Now, I want to have this done with MITM proxy.

[image: 3]

The MITM proxy fails at step no.12.
The SSL_do_handshake returns `('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'unknown alert type')` on client side.

The MITM proxy should understand the `SSL_do_handshake` at step no.12 and should not stop it.

I want my application to support the deep packet inspection proxies, hence testing this scenario.

Have tested with [mitmproxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmproxy.html), [burp proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) and [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) but had no luck.

How can I get through the step no.12?

Basic unit testing can be done with:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.cisco.com:443
[snip... a lot of openssl output]
---
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
R
RENEGOTIATING
[snip... certificate info]
verify return:1:
<Connection remains alive>
```