# Accepting SSL Connection in one process and continuing the communication in an unrelated process

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767529/how-to-accept-ssl-connection-in-one-process-and-reuse-the-same-ssl-context-in-an)  question was asked/answered approximately 7 years ago. I am asking this again since I was unable to find any working code example.

I have a server program written in C, which accepts a TLS connection and then starts (execv) a process to establish a session with the client.

This works fine without TLS as I am able to pass the socket descriptor(FD) to the new process. When TLS is enabled using OpenSSL, it is not enough to pass the FD to the new process instead the whole SSL context needs to be shared.

I have a temporary solution where I am using anonymous pipes (redirected stdin/stdout) to communicate using the main server process as proxy between the newly started program and the client. The client sends/receives using socket to main program while the main program send/receives using pipes with the newly created process. This solution has performance issues as the same message has to be sent twice i.e. once from new process to main process using pipes and then from main program to client using sockets.

Are there any code examples out there using file cache or shared memory where I can share the SSL context/session with the new program?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich According to the [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767529/how-to-accept-ssl-connection-in-one-process-and-reuse-the-same-ssl-context-in-an) it should be possible.

Comment: *"According to the old thread it should be possible."* - Based on the comments on the answer the proposed approach is not possible. The answer regarding in-kernel TLS is not relevant since you don't do in-kernel TLS but user space openssl. To cite from the last comment on the other answer regarding serializing the session object: *"As far as I can see, a SSL_SESSION is just some kind of handshake speedup cache. The actual connection is the SSL object, which isn't movable. This answer doesn't answer the question."*